# Run Jest on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, jestjs

I want to run a Jest test on AWS Lambda. However, it seems like Lambda doesn't recognize Jest's methods such as beforeAll, describe and test. Is there a way to configure Lambda such that Jest can be run similar to calling "npm test" on the local terminal line?

### screenshot of my error on Lambda

[image: A link to the screenshot of my error on Lambda]

And can somebody explain to me how does Jest work when we call "npm test" or "Jest" from terminal line? This may give me some insight on how to configure on Lambda.

Comment: Jest methods (like 'beforeAll') are global methods in the same way as 'require' is a global method. AWS Lambda allows you use libraries (through 'require') but it does not allow you to add global methods. There are ways of using Jest with aws-sdk-mock on local machines. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: @KMo I want to use Jest to run an end to end test on some webpages on lambda so that I can use aws cloudwatch scheduler to have periodic runs.

Comment: @lmc Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @jdcookie unfortunately nope

Comment: Yeah ok - for anyone finding this thread in the future, I ended up dropping Jest, and used Mocha. This package allowed it all to run quite easily https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-mocha-runner