# How to run jest using AWS Lambda?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to run my e2e test after deployment so I can roll back in case of any failure.
I followed the instruction described in [this blog](https://www.serverless.com/blog/manage-canary-deployments-lambda-functions-serverless-framework)

This is my lambda:

```js
export async function testLambda(event: APIGatewayEvent, context, callback) {
    console.log('The first version!')
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'The first version!'
        })
    }
    return callback(null, response)
}
```

this is my post hook:

```js
export async function postHook(event, context, callback) {

    const deploymentId = event.DeploymentId;
    const lifecycleEventHookExecutionId = event.LifecycleEventHookExecutionId;
    console.log(`deploymentId: ${deploymentId} - lifecycleEventHookExecutionId: ${lifecycleEventHookExecutionId}`)
    try {
        const jest = require('jest');
        require('ts-jest');
        const options = {
        projects: [__dirname],
        silent: true,
        };

        await jest.runCLI(options, options.projects);
            // update aws deployment for sucsses
        } catch (err) {
            // update aws deployment for failure
            console.log(err);
            return { statusCode: 500 }
    }
}
```

my test are written in typescript and I uploaded my jest.config.js and tsconfig.json to the serverless application zip file.
No matter what I do the global symbols of jest such as describe, expect etc... are not recognized:

> Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha` and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.

How can I run my test using aws lambda? the only choice I have is either trigger some other task  such as codebuild to run my test or change my test framework to mocha. is there any better solution?

Comment: Shouldn't those end-to-end tests be run outside of the Lambda? In your CI/CD pipeline for example? Typically, you would deploy your Lambdas, then run the tests in your CI/CD pipeline, validate the results and process the results in some form. Deploying that stuff alongside your Lambda appears to be the "wrong" approach.

Comment: The errors seem to come from typescript checking, did you try to install the `@types/jest` types? The type packages marks the `describe`  functions as available

Comment: The comments on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50768457/5560171 suggest that the issue is that AWS Lambda doesn't allow modules to add global methods

Answer (score -1):

Jest normally puts describe, test and other functions into the global context. When you start it programmatically it cannot do it, so you have to import these functions explicitly before use.

```
import { describe, test} from '@jest/globals';
```